# Configuring Remote Python Interpreter in Pycharm

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pycharm, remote-debugging, interpreter

I would like to connect to my raspberry pi using a remote interpreter. I've managed to do it just fine in windows 7 using Pycharm, but having recently upgrading to windows 8.1 it no longer works. I've tried to connect to the raspberry pi (where it worked in win 7) and another one with a fresh install of Raspbian (released 09-09-2014).

I also tried through Ubuntu, but to no avail. Has anyone out there managed to get this right in windows 8 or any linux flavour?

Should I try a key pair (OpenSSH or PuTTY)?

After adding the RSA key to the repository, the process that hangs is

'Getting remote interpreter version' ~ 'Connecting to 10.0.0.98'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works in PyCharm if you deploy a remote SFTP server.

Tools > Deployment > Add > Enter name and SFTP >

Enter host, port, root path (I said "/" without quotes) username and password.

Then, when creating a new project, change your interpreter to 'Deployment Configuration', and select your SFTP server.

Press OK, then create.

You should be all set to go.